# touch left / touch right events in reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm using reagent to develop a site. It's unclear to me how to work with touch events in reagent, actually, in general. I read this post 
[clojurescript: touch events and Domina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732028/clojurescript-touch-events-and-domina), but do i need to use domina to handle on-touch-start events with reagent ? Would anyone have a snippet of code to detect -- given a dom element -- if a user has swiped a % left or right  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reagent uses React's virtual DOM and synthetic events. Touch events are [available in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events) but you have to call `(.initializeTouchEvents js/React true)` before rendering any component (i.e. before calling `reagent.core/render-component`).

**Edit:** the code below won't work because touch events are more complex than mouse events. See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for some (JS) examples. React seems to implement the same touch API.

---

For the swipe percentage, do something like the following (untested):

```
(defn swipe-element []
  (let [swipe-state (atom {:width 0, :start-x 0, :current-x 0})]
    (fn []
      [:div {:on-touch-start 
             (fn [e]
               (reset! swipe-state {:width (.. e -target -offsetWidth)
                                    :start-x (.. e -target -pageX)
                                    :current-x (.. e -target -pageX)}))
             :on-touch-move
             (fn [e] 
               (swap! swipe-state assoc :current-x (.. e -target -pageX)))}
        (let [{:keys [width start-x current-x]} @swipe-state
              direction (if (> current-x start-x) "right" "left")]
          (str "Swipe " direction ": "
               (* (/ (.abs js/Math (- start-x current-x)) width) 100) "%")))))
```

Comment: actually on more testing... (.. e -target -pageX) is always undefined :/

Comment: Oh yeah it seems that touch events are more complex than mouse events... I did say it was untested. I'll edit the post.

Comment: This is close to being right, it looks as though you'd want

(aget e "touches" 0 "pageX") instead of (.. e -target -pageX)